# How to keep a deployment repo for Heroku within a development Git repo and keep them separate?

Tags: git, heroku

I have a git repo that I've used to develop out my app and now I want to deploy to Heroku. However I don't want to deploy this repo itself but rather a build of the code in this repo. My build system creates a `dist` directory within my repo directory that contains everything necessary for deployment anywhere. It is set up to be ignored in .gitignore because it's not necessary to store it as it can be rebuilt any time and would be redundant. However, Heroku needs a git repo for deployment. I could manually copy the output in `dist` to some other repo I keep around just for Heroku but that seems really ugly. I want to be able to develop source, build deployment code, and the push the former to GitHub/Lab and the latter to Heroku without overlap.

What I'd like is something like this: My `dist` folder is its own git repo, to satisfy Heroku, that isn't included in the parent dev repo's history, i.e. when I push my dev repo to GitHub or GitLab, the `dist` folder is ignored. When I push the contents of `dist` to Heroku, it has no knowledge of the fact that it's contained within a development project. This way my build process automatically changes my deployment repo, which I can make commits to when necessary to mark deployment events.

What I'm not sure about is how to set this up, if it's possible. I've heard horrible things about submodules and I'm not even sure that's the right tool for the job, as it seems to relate more to including other outside repos within mine. Here I want to create a repo that live only within my parent repo.

If there are others with a similar setup that know of something better than what I've asked for, I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 4):

I would create another branch called 'dist':

```
git checkout -b 'dist'
```

And inside that branch I would alter the gitignore file so that the 'dist' folder is included.

I'd then push my dist branch to heroku like so:

```
git push heroku dist:master
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: I'll give that a shot and see how it works. I'll see if I can't set up some sort of permanent merge strategy that prevents .gitignore from changing.

Comment: I built out a whole automated process around this // new branch, build out dist, commit, push, and then delete the branch .. so rad